# F150 blew out Dorman plug patch kit, safe to drive?

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, f-150

I have a 2005 F-150 STX (4.6L Triton) in which the spark plug in cylinder 3 blew out. I hired a mechanic to install a patch kit (he used the Dorman Help! Kit) and that kit itself also blew out of the engine. I'm currently working with the guy to try and get it fixed, but until then this truck is my daily driver, so my question is, if I disconnect the fuel injector to that cylinder, would it be safe to drive? It seems to run fine (other than being stupid loud again), but I don't want to risk it without another opinion.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Which Help! Kit?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it long term (if nothing else you're going to be doing interesting things to the block with the temperature differentials) but in the short term you should be okay. The piston will still be moving in the cylinder but since it's a four stroke engine it will still be getting appropriate lubrication.

You'll probably want to take it easy so as not to overwork the remaining cylinders and you'll almost certainly get a CEL on the dash at the very least but you should be able to get around. You *might* get the truck going into limp home mode which would further reduce the available power so you might not be going anywhere fast - and, as you've already discovered it will *sound* like crap but that's about it.